# Angular - no method sortable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui

I am including all necessary scripts **(The error was in order of the scripts + missing jQuery)**:

```
<script src="scripts/vendor/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular-ui/build/angular-ui.js"></script>
```

And using this code snippet:

```
<div ng:controller="controller">
    <ul ui:sortable ng:model="list">
        <li ng:repeat="item in list" class="item">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
    <hr />
    <div ng:repeat="item in list">{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sortable'
```

Anybody ever experienced the same and knows the way out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are missing [jquery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/) library. angular-ui make use of jquery-ui library to provide sortable functionality.

angular-ui library depends on jquery-ui library, so download and add the jquery-ui.css and jquery-ui.js to the project.

Also jquery-ui needs [jquery library](http://jquery.com/), so if you have not included it, download an include it also.

Comment: Really? I thought they said that no other dependencies are needed :(

Comment: HA!

`Optional` **Include jQuery if using jQuery Plugins** and
`Optional` **Include any jQuery(UI) plugins you wish to use (plugins are not bundled with AngularUI)**

Comment: @Michal no, angular-ui provides the required directive support, but the actual implementation is provided by jquery-ui

Comment: Included these and no change:(

`<script src="components/jquery-ui-1.10.2/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="components/jquery-ui-1.10.2/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Comment: these should be included before `scripts/vendor/angular/angular.js`

Comment: meh, it's not in the scripts, they are loaded, I checked in the console

Comment: the order of scripts also is important, can you update script order in the question

Comment: You gotta be kidding me...so why exactly is the order of the scripts so important?(Like - how come it's working when I changed the order) Got it working now...

Comment: It is because of `angular`'s dependency on jquery.

Comment: In our kind of profession learning never stops... so enjoy doing it every day